# 2.83 Grease pencil: No anti-aliasing

Tags: grease-pencil, antialiasing

All strokes made with Grease Pencil (Blender 2.83) have jagged edges. Both in the view port and in the render (Cycles and Eevee).
I've increased smooth, iterations, subdivision steps etc for the grease pencil, and I've tried various settings of anti-aliasing threshold in the render settings (0 - 2.000) without any luck

[image]

The only option I've found is to add a Blur effect, but that's not the same effect as anti-aliasing.

At my wits end. Any pointers?

Setup

- Blender: 2.83
- OS: Win10
- Pen: Wacom Intuos Pro (small)
- GPU: Nvidia RTX 2080 ti
- Laptop: Acer Predator Triton 500

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Seems to be a 2.83 bug. I would recommend downloading the 2.9 Beta. My strokes are now much smoother without any subdivision and my scenes run far better (much lower load on the GPU). Of course this version isn't "stable" so use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Matt! I will try out the 2.9 beta...at my own risk